# Strange error when trying to create a database using EF4.1 Code First

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

Im using the EF4.1 with code first to create a database.

I have my model in mvc3 that looks like this

```
    public class BusinessContactDetailsModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Contact Date")]
        public DateTime ContactDate { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 5)]
        [Display(Name = "Outcome Rating")]
        public int OutcomeRating { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Comment { get; set; }


        public int BusinessId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Method of Contact")]
        public int FormOfContactId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Follow up Date")]
        public DateTime FollowUpDate { get; set; }

    }
```

Which fails when I try to run the application during the build process. I know its the FollowUpProperty that is causing the problem as its a new property I have just added and whats strange is if I change the property from a DateTime to an Int it works ok.

Has anyone else had this kind of problem?

My stack trace looks like

> [SqlCeException (0x80004005): An overflow occurred while converting to datetime.]
>      System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr) +125
>      System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommandText(IntPtr& pCursor, Boolean& isBaseTableCursor) +631
>      System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options) +509
>      System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +46
>      System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeMultiCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +152
>      System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeMultiCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +36
>      System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
>      System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues) +8118684
>      System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter) +267

[UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter) +389
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache) +163
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) +609
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +326

[DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +372
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() +48
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() +47
   System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +502
   System.Data.Entity.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.b_*0(DbContext c) +143
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c*_DisplayClass5.b__3() +59
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +101

[DataException: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +157
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +260
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.b__4(InternalContext c) +31
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +147
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +276
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +112
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +41
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +34
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +148
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +33
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +91
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +315
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   MyApplication.CRM.Controllers.BusinessController.Index() in C:\Users\sp\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MyApplication.CRM\MyApplication.CRM\Controllers\BusinessController.cs:23
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +96
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass15.b*_12() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult *) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClasse.b_*d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b*_0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8862381
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Comment: It turns out it was because the DateTime was not nullable. I changed it to allow null dates and it works fine now.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out it was because the DateTime was not nullable. I changed it to allow null dates and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case a TimeSpan was initialized to 30 hours, which caused an exception when casted to t-sql! Dumb EF 5.0 RTM!